# Does toggling the "Highest connection speed" setting turn off the LTE radio?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, cellular-data

I was wondering if I toggling **Highest connection speed** in the **cellular** settings menu turns off a separate piece of hardware (the LTE radio).

[image: Windows Phone Cellular Setings LTE][image: Windows Phone Cellular Setings 3G]

Are the LTE and 2G/3G radios the same components, or would disabling the LTE radio shutdown a piece of hardware.

The reason I'm asking is because I was wondering if setting it at 3G could save some battery life when there is no LTE coverage.

If it matters I am using a Lumia 920.

Comment: This post has been flagged as off topic. Perhaps you can rephrase it to be more specific to Windows Phone (or why it matters on Windows Phone)?

Comment: @row1 Sure thing. Please let me know if it's still off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know technically if it turn some hardware off but indeed if you set to a lower connection speed your phone will stop to search for this.

Imagine you are in some place here 3G is good but 4G not. If your phone has the connection speed set to 4G it will keep trying get this speed for you. But if you set to 3G as soon as it gets a 3G network its stop to search for a higher one.

Nokia gave me part of this info and said that for places where you don't have good 3G its works the same if you set to 2G.

The summary is:

Does the phone shutdown some part of hardware? I don't know.
Does the phone save some battery in specify occasions? Yes.

Comment: Thanks Vitor, I +1'ed, since at least I know I'll save battery life, but I'm going to let this hang out here a bit more.

Comment: Thank's. Good to hear that. ;)